# How to add hash in dynamically import chunk name?

Tags: webpack

I need to add the build hash to dynamically imported chunk name. Things with placeholders (example: /* webpackChunkName: "MainPage.[hash]" */) doesn't work.

`() => import(/ webpackChunkName: "MainPage.[hash]" / './Pages/MainPage');`

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found an answer. There is a [output.chunkFilename](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputchunkfilename) option for that.